# specifying random effect as offset in logistic glm (R)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, offset

I am working on a measurement error model for presence/absence data using a variant of a Monte Carlo EM (MCEM) algorithm for model fitting. As part of this approach, I simulate random effects by taking random draws from a known distribution [1]. I then need to pass these simulated random effects as an offset to a logistic GLM.

Most comments I have found on specifying offsets in a GLM address Poisson regression with a log-link or Binomial regression when adjusting the number of trials ([Using offset in binomial model to account for increased numbers of patients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25415/using-offset-in-binomial-model-to-account-for-increased-numbers-of-patients), [How to formulate the offset of a GLM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237963/how-to-formulate-the-offset-of-a-glm)).

I am wondering how I might write my model down in statistical notation to see how these offsets should be correctly specified (similar to what is shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/237980/263539), but for my purposes).

My instinct is that they should be specified linearly, as in

```
glm(y ~ W1 + W2, 
    offset = V_sim,
    family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

where `y` is Bernoulli, `W1` and `W2` are covariates, and `V_sim` is my vector of simulated random effects. However, from the [comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35258/263539) on some of these posts, it seems that passing offsets in the logistic setting might be different from other settings.

[1] The variance of the random effects is estimated in a previous GLMM fit with a similar model form to the GLM with offsets, except that group membership for the random effects was specified as a random intercept (instead of being specified as an offset).